# SectionList Component not Scrolling till the end inside Accordion Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried to make SectionList Component inside Accordion Component, List is rendered but I can't scroll it till the end, some item in the last section not appearing. I have tried to remove all styling, wrap the SectionList Component in `<View></View>` and add `style={{flex:1}}`, but not working. Here is the code example:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";
import * as Village from "./mydb";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: undefined
    };
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
  }
  renderSelectedItem(){
   switch(this.state.selected){
      case '4001':
        return <Village.A/>
      case '4002':
        return <Village.B/>
      default:
        return null
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selected}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Village A" value='4001'/>
          <Picker.Item label="Village B" value='4002'/>
        </Picker>
        {this.renderSelectedItem()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

A.js/B.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, SectionList, StatusBar } from "react-native";

const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps",  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer",  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream",  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  }
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

export default class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SectionList
        sections={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
          <Text>{title}</Text>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
};
```

when I copied the A.js/B.js code and replace in App.js, it works normally, the problem occured when I render the sectionList Component inside the Accordion Component. how to make the SectionList scroll normally till the end inside the Accordion Component?